# Node.js Streams: Is there a way to convert or wrap a fs write stream to a Transform stream?

Tags: node.js, http, stream

With a node http server I'm trying to pipe the request read stream to the response write stream with some intermediary transforms, one of which is a file system write.

The pipeline looks like this with non pertinent code removed for simplicity:

```
function handler (req, res) {
  req.pipe(jsonParse())
     .pipe(addTimeStamp())
     .pipe(jsonStringify())
     .pipe(saveToFs('saved.json'))
     .pipe(res);
}
```

The custom Transform streams are pretty straight forward, but I have no elegant way of writing `saveToFs`. It looks like this:

```
function saveToFs (filename) {
  const write$ = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  write$.on('open', () => console.log('opened'));
  write$.on('close', () => console.log('closed'));

  const T = new Transform();
  T._transform = function (chunk, encoding, cb) {
    write$.write(chunk);
    cb(null, chunk);
  }
  return T;
}
```

The idea is simply to pipe the data to the write stream and then through to the response stream, but `fs.createWriteStream(<file.name>)` is only a writable stream, so it makes this approach difficult.

Right now this code has two problems that I can see: the write stream never fires a close event (memory leak?), and I would like the data to pass through the file system write before returning data to the response stream instead of essentially multicasting to two sinks.

Any suggestions, or pointing out fundamental things I've missed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked my answer @MFave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is save the `stream` returned by the `.pipe` before `saveToFs`, and then pipe that to a file and `res`.

```
function handler(req, res) {
    const transformed = req.pipe(jsonParse())
        .pipe(addTimeStamp())
        .pipe(jsonStringify());

    transformed.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('saved.json'));
    transformed.pipe(res);
}
```

To sum it up, you can pipe the same readable stream (`transformed`) to multiple writable streams.

> And I would like the data to pass through the file system write
>   before returning data to the response stream instead of essentially
>   multicasting to two sinks.

Use `{ end: false }` option when piping to `res`.

```
transformed.pipe(res, { end: false });
```

And then call `res.end()` when the file is written or whenever you want.